# Matching Text Values in XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm running into an odd issue that has me tearing my hair out. I'm attempting to match an XPath in my stylesheet. It works when I hardcode the matching value, but not when I try to get it from a variable. What am I doing wrong here?

XML input (obviously very simplified):

```
    <container>
      <items>
        <item>
          <LocationID>LOCATION_4</LocationID>
        </item>
        <item>
          <LocationID>LOCATION_4</LocationID>
        </item>
      </items>
    </container>
```

XSLT Template ($DistinctLocations and $dataNode are previously declared variables, my first couple of printouts are to verify they are both in scope)

```
    <xsl:template name="LocationTemplate">

      <xsl:for-each select="$DistinctLocations/Location">
        <MY-CURRITEM>
          <val>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
          </val>
          <distinct>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$DistinctLocations" />
          </distinct>
          <node>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$dataNode" />
          </node>
          <itemloc>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$dataNode//item[LocationID = 'LOCATION_4'][1]/LocationID" />
          </itemloc>
          <itemlocdot>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$dctNode//risk[LocationID = .][1]/LocationID" />
          </itemlocdot>
          <itemloctext>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$dctNode//risk[LocationID = text()][1]/LocationID" />
          </itemloctext>
          <itemloc2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$dataNode//item[string(LocationID) = string(.) ][1]/LocationID" />
          </itemloc2>
          <itemloc3>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$dataNode//item[string(LocationID) = string(text()) ][1]/LocationID" />
          </itemloc3>
        </MY-CURRITEM>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

The output:

```
<MY-CURRITEM>
  <val>
    <Location>LOCATION_4</Location>
  </val>
  <distinct>
    <DistinctLocations>
      <Location>LOCATION_4</Location>
    </DistinctLocations>
  </distinct>
  <node>
    <container>
      <items>
        <item>
          <LocationID>LOCATION_4</LocationID>
        </item>
        <item>
          <LocationID>LOCATION_4</LocationID>
        </item>
      </items>
    </container>
  </node>
  <itemloc>
    <LocationID>LOCATION_4</LocationID>
  </itemloc>
  <itemlocdot />
  <itemloctext />
  <itemloc2 />
  <itemloc3 />
</MY-CURRITEM>
```

As you can see, the  node where I hard-coded the value returns a match. All of the others, where I attempt to match the value from a variable, fail to match. Since the hard-code works, I'm guessing it's some kind of mismatch between types, but I've tried all of combinations of type-casting I can think of and I'm not getting any results.

**EDIT**: People are requesting the whole stylesheet. It's huge and will take some time to simplify. In the mean time, here's where thevariables came from:

$DistinctLocations is a param passed in from C#

```
args.AddParam("DistinctLocations", string.Empty, xDistinctLocs.CreateNavigator().Select("/"));
```

and

```
<xsl:param name="DistinctLocations" />
```

$dataNode is the original XML that is being transformed, stored in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="dataNode" select="." />
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: I'm not sure what you mean by that? I'm just generally printing out a bunch of stuff to make sure I'm not making any assumptions.

Comment: Please post the entire XSL, we are missing some crucial informations such as how each of the variable are set.

Comment: Its hard to tell because your code is not complete. For example `$DistinctLocations` looks important but you dont show how this variable is declared, which I am bet is important.

Comment: Why don't you post a simplified example, that we could run *as is* without guessing what you did.

Comment: "*People are requesting the whole stylesheet.*"  No, people are requesting **minimal** but **complete** code, that can be used to reproduce the issue simply by copying it and running it. Your example is still not up to that. I have posted an answer that I *think* addresses the issue you are complaining about - but I am not at all sure about that. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please observe the folowing simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <locations>
        <location>LOCATION_2</location>
    </locations>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <location>LOCATION_1</location>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <location>LOCATION_2</location>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="locations/location">
            <location>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </value>
                <hard-code>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="//item[location='LOCATION_2']" />
                </hard-code>
                <dot>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="//items/item[location=.]" />
                </dot>
                <current>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="//items/item[location=current()]" />
                </current>
            </location>          
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <location>
      <value>LOCATION_2</value>
      <hard-code>
         <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <location>LOCATION_2</location>
         </item>
      </hard-code>
      <dot/>
      <current>
         <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <location>LOCATION_2</location>
         </item>
      </current>
   </location>
</root>
```

Why is the `<dot>` element of the result empty? Because in the expression:

```
"//items/item[location=.]"
```

the inner dot represents the outer`item` node - not the current `location` node. The expression is looking for an `item` whose value is equal to the value of its `location` child. Of course, no such item exists.

This is why XSLT added the [current() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#misc-func), which does not change context when used in a predicate.

Comment: Good grief, that was exactly it. Thanks!